# Find limit of sequence using integral

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, summation, riemann-sum

Given sequence $$a_m = \frac{1}{m^2} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^m \sqrt[3]{(mx + k + 1)\cdot (mx + k)^2}$$

Find its limit using integral.

I thought it may be solved using either Euler-Mclaurin formula or Riemann sum. Unfortunately, the function under the sum sign is pretty uncomfy to operate with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
a_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \sqrt[3]{(nx + k + 1)\cdot (nx + k)^2}&= \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \sqrt[3]{\left(x + \frac{k+1}{n}\right)\cdot \left(x + \frac{k}{n}\right)^2}
\end{align}
$$ giving
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\sqrt[3]{\left(x + \frac{k}{n}\right)^3}\le a_n \le \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\sqrt[3]{\left(x + \frac{k+1}{n}\right)^3}
$$ or
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\left(x + \frac{k}{n}\right)\le a_n \le \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\left(x + \frac{k+1}{n}\right)
$$ that is $$
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\left(x + \frac{k}{n}\right)}\le a_n \le \color{blue}{\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\left(x + \frac{k}{n}\right)}+\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\frac{1}{n}
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: You meant $\sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ on RHS?

Comment: @Negligible Senescence No, it is $\sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: I will have to find blue sum using Riemann sum. Since $n \to \infty \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and then $\lim a_n$ is equal to blue sum?

Comment: @Negligible Senescence Yes, we have $\frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n} \cdot n \times \frac1n=\frac1n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.